# Custom open with action for a file type: double click a certain file type logs file's location

Tags: bash

I need the following behavior. If user selects one or more `*.mp3` files and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> the list of files is saved to `~/Documents/mp3log.log`.

I guess I need to set open with to a custom bash script, but what should this script contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a simple task, you just need to “open” the file(s) with an executable script like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo $@ >>~/Documents/mp3log.log
for i in "$@"; do
  xdg-open "$i"
done
```

`xdg-open "$@"` may be a better alternative for the loop if you want to deal with just a single file type here – of course you can also skip `xdg-open` and open it directly with the desired program, e.g. `vlc "$@"`.

To run the selected files through the script by default just make it the default for the desired file type using your file manager.